# dotenv file is not working in MERN Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I have created a MERN Project after creating all components and backend setup i want to hide all my important info from public so that i installed dotenv package and created a file .env in root and for testing purpose i printed value in console log but it shows error undefined.

In `.env` file in root I added a variable for testing purpose I added:

```
REACT_APP_PORT=1500
```

Variable and then I restart my server. In index.js file I require:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

I also tried another methods:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()
```

And then when I tried to print PORT value on console:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_PORT)
```

It shows undefined error. I tried many time with different ways but got undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: MERN consists of two servers : `Expressjs` (server-side) and `Reactjs` (client-side), which means you must have two files of `package.json` in two different folders. make sure to run `npm install dotenv` in the server side app folder.

Comment: @omar two servers? You mean a client and a server?

Comment: Your client and server should be two separate directories or projects. The client should only communicate with the server over a host and IP. The client (React) needs a package and env, and the server (Express) needs its own package and env. The two code-bases should not know about each other.

Comment: Yes! I have installed dotenv in server folder. I have already two package json files on both folders.